# SQL SERVER 2008 - Sqlcmd: Error: Internal error at ReadText (Reason: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, command-line, ssms

I'm using **MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2** and try to use `sqlcmd` from command prompt. But getting this error when I try to run `sqlcmd` with `-i` command, which is for input file.

This command which is executing simple `test.sql`(containing only `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` for test purposes) gives an error:

> sqlcmd -S serverName -i test.sql

BUT, this command works well (I just specify command by `-q` query, instead of reading from file):

> sqlcmd -S serverName -q "SELECT @@SERVERNAME"

the error message is:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Internal error at ReadText (Reason: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page).

Some issues on google say that this was a known bug and was fixed in `SP1`, I have installed it but still getting the same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing Computer/VM locale and region to US solved the problem.